# Create an Object from a external javascript Using Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

So I have a Class called AppController from an external js file. 
by the way I'm using Angular.cli 
so I managed to import this script on the .angular-cli.json under the scripts section

```
 "scripts": [
"./assets/blockly/demos/blockfactory/app_controller.js"
]
```

and then declared a variable on my component

```
declare var apc:any
```

now i'm trying to create an object using that class

```
 blocklyFactory = new apc.AppController();
```

but I'm getting and error saying that AppController is undefined.

here is the full component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


declare var Blockly: any;
declare var blocklyFactory;
declare var apc: any;



@Component({
  selector: 'app-cmpbuilder',
  templateUrl: './cmpbuilder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cmpbuilder.component.css']
})
export class CmpbuilderComponent implements OnInit {
  workspacePlayground: any;

  public toolbox: string =
  `<xml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="blockfactory_toolbox"         class="toolbox">
  <category name="Component Containers">
      <block type="component_container"></block>
      <block type="settings_container"></block>
    </category>
<category name="Basic Components">
  <block type="field_static"></block>
  <block type="field_input"></block>
  <block type="field_number"></block>
  <block type="field_angle"></block>
  <block type="field_dropdown"></block>
  <block type="field_checkbox"></block>
  <block type="field_colour"></block>
  <block type="colour_hue"><mutation colour="20"></mutation><field name="HUE">20</field></block>
  <block type="field_variable"></block>
  <block type="field_image"></block>
</category>
<category colour="280" name="Component Settings">
    <block type="behaviour_settings"></block>
</category>
</xml>
`;

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {

      blocklyFactory = new apc.AppController();
      blocklyFactory.init();
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload',    blocklyFactory.confirmLeavePage);
      window.addEventListener('load', this.ngOnInit);
    this.createBlocks();

  }

  createBlocks() {
    this.workspacePlayground = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv',
                {toolbox: this.toolbox});


    return this.workspacePlayground;
  }

}
```